# Accessing a search field in an iframe using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, iframe, automation

Alright, I have tried for many hours to access a search text box inside an iframe using VBA, and all attempts have failed. I've done my research on this both on here and other websites, but nothing seems to work. To preface, my code currently navigates to my desired website and clicks on a button that opens up a pop-up iFrame window. I need to access a textbox in the iframe popup and input a value into it.

Here's the portion of my code where I'm trying to access the iFrame (as well as some my commented out failed attempts).

```
Public Sub FillOutOrder()

 Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("AddItems()", "JavaScript") 'Opens up the iFrame pop-up
 Dim iframe As Object
 Set iframe = ie.document.frames("ModalContainerDivframe") 'Name of the iFrame 
 iframe.document.getElementById("spWin_SearchProducts").Value = "266050104" 'id Value of the iFrame Search Box
 '^ This code is my last failed attempt. It just results in an error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   The code below are things I have tried that haven't worked.

'    Set iDoc = ie.document.frames("ModalContainerDivframe").document
'     For Each iFrame In iDoc
'                  If iFrame.ID = "spWin_SearchProducts" Then
'                      iFrame.value = "266050104"
'                      Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE:     DoEvents: Loop
'                      Do Until ie.document.readyState = "complete":   DoEvents: Loop
'                  Exit For
'                  End If
'              Next


 'iFrame source URL
 '../common/popups/searchproducts2_container.cfm?  Type=Master&SubType=BO&theId=6248538&dellocID=460418&showPriceQuantity=1&maskSave=1&_Key=5AF2B88C9056EF8DA4DFEAD048BDCDA3B7FC5D9B7B845D9A40D1942892D8AB460F83D1819EBA895E0CDF2A88DD6E96E9ABCE3CD454B8DFB9D208D2A9FCCD0581CC0CC09F2982851C989099D180EAC5D2DE1ECF9C91B410B6A89616987EEC57A1EB4CBB9E4ED4C15EAE459038464D48D217&_r=4.488391390158245

'Current Window URL 
'https://www.oms.itradenetwork.com/2/buy/mo_details.cfm?theID=6248543&_Key=5678A0738A999603B58C17AF9151A8875F9F905AC600C1DBF6CBCAD5 

End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any thoughts on how to solve this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Your URL is not accessible, so I'm not sure how anyone could help with this.

Comment: I can navigate to the [link you provided](https://www.oms.itradenetwork.com/2/buy/mo_details.cfm?theID=6248543&_Key=5678A0738A999603B58C17AF9151A8875F9F905AC600C1DBF6CBCAD5), but I'm redirected to logon page, where can I get credentials?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem? I have the same question.